# How to get url from Rewrite?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem that prevents me get the URL:
this is my apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./tmp/user.php?action=$0 [QSA]
```

this is my php:

```
   <?php
         if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
         echo $_GET['action'];
         }
   ?>
```

In html directory i have tmp directory, and when i trying to get example localhost/tmp url web open directory. I do not need that, I need that web show url.

Maybe someone can help ?